# node.js - Hosting server on public IP with socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, networking, socket.io

Consider the server code:

```
express = require('express');
app = express();
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/'));
http = require('http').Server(app);
io = require('socket.io')(http);
...
http.listen(80);
```

I have also tried `http.listen(80, "::")`.

And the client code:

```
socket = io();
```

This leads to the following console error when entering http://[#PUBLIC_IPv6_OF_SERVER]:3000 in the browser:

```
ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

How can I successfully enable clients to connect to the server through its public IPv6 address?

Comment: What version of node.js are you running?  What version of socket.io?

Comment: @jfriend00 Node.js 0.12.0, not sure which version of socket.io.

Comment: Per a comment in [this article](http://code.danyork.com/2011/01/21/how-to-use-node-js-with-ipv6/) and [the beginning of this article](http://benno.id.au/blog/2011/08/13/nodejs-ipv6), I wonder if you need to do `http.listen(3000, "::");` to get the server to listen on both IPv6 and IPv4 addresses.

Comment: @jfriend00 Did not change anything. Apparently I'm using socket.io-1.2.0.

Comment: Per this [socket.io issue description in 2012](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/issues/260#ref-issue-46596395), there was a point in time when socket.io did not properly parse ipV6 URLs and would not work.  I have no idea if this has since been fixed or not and you haven't said which version of socket.io you're using either.

Comment: @jfriend socket.io-1.2.0 ^^

Comment: FYI, using socket.io 1.4.5 and node.js 5.11 and chrome, I have no problem connecting to my local server using `var socket = io()` when the URL of the page is this: `http://[fe80::fdc6:af6b:699c:7c74]/socket-io-test-client.html` and the server is started with `var server = app.listen(80);`.  So, clearly these versions of socket.io and node.js support IPv6 connections in the usual way.

Comment: I should add that I was running on Windows 10.

Answer (score -1):

You need to allow cross origin request on server side.

```
var domains = "http://localhost:*";
io = require('socket.io')(http, {origins:domains});
```